# Can you open the file explorer using a Kivy Python Applicaiton?

Tags: python, kivy, material-design, kivymd

Quick question. I am creating an application using Kivy. On one of the applications screens, it has a button for uploading a file. Is there a way that I can bind a button (such as a MDRaisedButton) so that it opens the users computers default file explorer outside of the application rather than trying to embed it?

Answer (score 0):

### According to the docs provided at [`https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html)

> There are two ready-to-use widgets that provide views of the file system. Each of these present the files and folders in a different style.

#### - The **FileChooserListView**

displays file entries as text items in a vertical list, where folders can be collapsed and expanded.
[image]

#### - The FileChooserIconView presents icons and text from left to right, wrapping them as required.

[image]

---

You can import it like this:

```py
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserIconView, FileChooserListView
```